# how to get outline view to open at the same levels as before for a microsoft word document

Tags: microsoft-word

Microsoft has never made sticky the outline levels of a word .docx file.
I've been using it since 1992.
By default, when doc is opened, all levels are at 1.

Comment: In versions of Word beginning with Word 2013 there has been an option to collapse outline-level styles by default. You can check the style definition to make sure that this is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

The safe way to do this is to put the following code into your Normal template:

```
Sub ViewOutline()
    With ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View
     .Type = wdOutlineView
     .ShowHeading 9
     .ShowAllHeadings
    End With
End Sub
```

If you try to execute a "...ShowAllHeadings" command and the active document is not in Outline view, an error is generated. The above code only executes when you switch to Outline View.